# BST inorder method referencing vector showing error: declaration is incompatible

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree

I am a beginner at c++ and I am coding a program that stores data into a BST template class the  being another class called log_t that stores the variables, I am trying to use the inorder method from the BST class to reference a vector from main, to input the values into and be able to use it in the main class

my main class

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

   BST<log_t> l;

string infilename = "";

string filePath = "data\\";
string files[1] = {
    filePath + "MetData-31-3a.csv"
    //filePath + "Jan20071toDec31abcdefghijklmnopq",
    //filePath + "Jan20081toDec31abcdefghijklmnopq",
    //filePath + "MetData_Jan01-2010-Jan01-2011-ALL"

};

/// checks if file can open
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    infilename = files[i];
    ifstream infile(infilename);

    if (!infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "unable to read file" << files[i] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "reading file" << files[i] << endl;
    }

    /* parse sensor data csv file */
    string tmp;
    getline(infile, tmp);  // skip the first line


    while (getline(infile, tmp))

    {
        // if successfully parsed then append into vector
        log_t logline;
        if (ParseLog(tmp, logline))
            l.insert(logline);

    }
}

cout << " end with reading file" << endl;


/* aggregate/filter logs */

Vector<log_t> vec;
l.inorder(vec);

 /* prompt menu */

// this array stores all the menu option callback functions
void(*funs[])(const Vector<log_t> & vec) = { NULL, &option1, &option2, &option3, &option4, &option5,&option6 };

// keep printing menu in loop
while (true)
{
    // prompt menu and ask user to select option
    int choice = PromptMenu();

    // check validity of choice
    if (choice < 1 || choice > 6)
    {
        cout << "invalid choice" << endl;


    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl;

        // call menu option handler
        (funs[choice])(vec);
    }

}
system("pause");
return -1;
}
```

my BST class

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <stream>
 #include "date.h"
 #include "times.h"
 #include "log_t.h"
 #include "Vector.h"

 using namespace std;

 template <class T>
 class BST {

 private:

    struct Node {
    T num;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    };

Node* root = NULL;
Node* insert(Node* node, T x);
Node* newnode(T num);
void removeprivate(T num, Node* parent);
T findsmallestprivate(Node* ptr);
void inorderprivate(Node* ptr, void (BST<T>::* FT)(T&), Vector<log_t>const& log);
void postorderprivate(Node* ptr, void (BST<T>::* FT)(T&));
void preorderprivate(Node* ptr, void (BST<T>::* FT)(T&));
//void inorderprivate(Node* ptr);
//void postorderprivate(Node* ptr);
//void preorderprivate(Node* ptr);
void removematch(Node* parent, Node* match, bool left);


public:
void insert(T num);
void remove(T num);
void removerootmatch();
T findsmallest();
void inorder(Vector<log_t>const& log);
void postorder();
void preorder();
void print(T& p) { cout << p << " "; };

};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::inorder(Vector<log_t>const& log) {
inorderprivate(root,print,log);

}

template <class T>
 void BST<T>::inorderprivate(Node* ptr, void (BST<T>::* FT)(T&), Vector<log_t>const& 
 log) {
 if (root != NULL)
 {

    if (ptr->left != NULL)
    {
        inorderprivate(ptr->left, FT);
    }
    (this->*FT)(log);
    log.Append( ptr->num);
    if (ptr->right != NULL)
    {
        inorderprivate(ptr->right, FT);
    
    }
   }

  else
  {
    cout << "tree is empty";
   }
  }
```

my log_t class the T type

```
 #pragma once 
  #ifndef LOG_T_H
  #define LOG_T_H

  #include <iostream>
  #include <stream>
  #include <string>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <stream>
  #include "date.h"
  #include "times.h"
  #include "BST.h"

   class log_t
   {
   public:

   log_t();
   log_t(log_t& log);

   float gettemp();

   float getwind();

   float getsolar();

   void setwind(float wind);


   void setsolar(float rad);


   void settemp(float temp);

   Date date;
   Times time;


   private:


   float wind_speed;
  float solar_radiation;
  float air_temperature;

   };


   log_t::log_t()
   {
    wind_speed = 0;
    solar_radiation = 0;
    air_temperature = 0;
    }

    log_t::log_t(log_t& log) {
    wind_speed = log.wind_speed;
    solar_radiation = log.solar_radiation;
    air_temperature = log.air_temperature;
    date.SetDate(log.date.GetDay(), log.date.GetMonth(), log.date.GetYear());
    time.SetHour(log.time.GetHour());
    time.SetMinute(log.time.GetMinute());

    }

    float log_t:: gettemp()
    {
    return air_temperature;
     }

    float log_t::getwind() {
    return wind_speed;
      }

   float log_t::getsolar() {
    return solar_radiation;
    }

   void log_t::setwind(float wind)
   {
    wind_speed = wind;
    }

    void log_t::setsolar(float rad)
     {
    
    solar_radiation = rad;
    
     }

     void log_t::settemp(float temp)
     {
    
    air_temperature = temp;
     }




     #endif // LOG_T_H
```

my vector class

```
      #pragma once
      #ifndef VECTOR_H
      #define VECTOR_H
      #include <iostream>
       #include <stream>
       #include <string>
    template <class T>
     class Vector
      {
         public:
          Vector();
          Vector(int capacity);
          Vector(const Vector& vec);
          Vector& operator=(const Vector& vec);
          ~Vector();

          int GetSize() const;
          void Expand();
          T& GetLast();
          void Append(const T& val);
          T& operator[](int idx);
          const T& operator[](int idx) const;

           private:
            T* elems;
            int capacity;/** < int capacity, stores the size of the array */
            int count;

            void CopyFrom(const Vector& vec);
      };


       template <class T>
       inline Vector<T>::Vector() : elems(nullptr), capacity(0), count(0)
        {
        }


        template <class T>
         inline Vector<T>::Vector(int capacity)
          : elems(new T[capacity]()), capacity(capacity), count(0)
          {
          }

          template <class T>
           inline Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector& vec)
            {
              CopyFrom(vec);
             }

         template <class T>
         inline Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& vec)
          {
           if (elems)
           delete[] elems;
           CopyFrom(vec);
           return *this;
           }


          template <class T>
          inline Vector<T>::~Vector()
          {
             if (elems)
             delete[] elems;
           }

           template <class T>
           inline int Vector<T>::GetSize() const
            {
                   return count;
             }

              template <class T>
              inline void Vector<T>::Expand()
               {
                 ++count;
                 if (count > capacity)
                  if (capacity)
                  capacity *= 2;
                   else
                  capacity = 4;
                  T* tmp = new T[capacity]();
                  for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i)
                   tmp[i] = elems[I];
                   if (elems)
                   delete[] elems;
                   elems = tmp;
               }

          template <class T>
           inline T& Vector<T>::GetLast()
           {
                 return elems[count - 1];
            }

            template <class T>
             inline void Vector<T>::Append(const T& oval)
             {

                 Expand();
                 GetLast() = val;

              }

             template <class T>
             inline T& Vector<T>::operator[](int idx)
             {
               return elems[idx];
              }

           template <class T>
           inline const T& Vector<T>::operator[](int idx) const
           {
             return elems[idx];
           }

         template <class T>
         inline void Vector<T>::CopyFrom(const Vector& vec)
          {
           elems = new T[vec.capacity]();
            capacity = vec.capacity;
           count = vec.count;
           for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            elems[i] = vec.elems[i];
           }

           #endif //VECTOR_H
```

the errors that keep showing up are

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "void BST::inorder(const Vector<> &log)" (declared at line 241 of "C:\Users\Frances\Documents\A2\A2\BST.h") A2  C:\Users\Frances\Documents\A2\A2\BST.h  241

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'log_t': undeclared identifier  A2  C:\Users\Frances\Documents\A2\A2\BST.h  33

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2923   'Vector': 'log_t' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'   A2  C:\Users\Frances\Documents\A2\A2\BST.h  33

could someone help me figure out what it is that's causing this or what I am doing wrong, I have been trying to find an answer for hours and haven't been successful thank you

Comment: you posted lots of code but the relevant part I cannot find. What is `option1`, `option2` etc?

Comment: please post a [mre], pay attention to both minimal and reproducible

Comment: `inorderprivate(ptr->left, FT);` - how many arguments does `inorderprivate` require ? Hmmmm. And fyi, `inorderprivate(root,print,log)` should be `inorderprivate(root,&BST<T>::print,log)`

Comment: You have a circular dependency between "BST.h" and "log_t.h". Why does "log_t.h" include "BST.h" at all?

Comment: option 1 and option 2 are part of the main class they are separate methods , I can add them in if you like ?

Comment: in order private should have 3 arguments(Node*node, function pointer, vector reference)

Comment: its not about what I like ;). If you post a [mre], others can copy the code and reproduce the same error as you get. The code you did post will produce errors that are maybe not related to your question, that makes it more difficult to help you

Comment: Fix the circular dependency first. Don't `#include` anything in a file that you don't actually need in that file.

Comment: Okay so sorry for the late reply, you were right the #include BST in the log_t class was causing all the errors, thank you so much The program is fully functional now